# How to use Stanford parser to generate the English sentence from given segmented nodes

Tags: algorithm, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, language-translation

I am trying to develop a Sinhala (My native language) to English translator.
Still I am thinking for an approach.

**If I however parse a sentence of my language, then can use that for generating english sentence with the help of stanford parser. Or is there any other method you can recommend.**

And I am thinking of a bottom up parser for my language, but still have no idea how to implement. Any suggestions for steps I can follow.

Thanks 
Mathee

Comment: I think I am asking for a reverse mechanism for a parser to generate sentences. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Google for "morphological generator". You still need something to fix syntactic issues like word order, agreement, etc.

Comment: http://staff.sjp.ac.lk/budditha/publications also seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough amounts of bilingual corpora then the best thing you can do is to train a model using an existing statistical machine translation system like [Moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/). Modern phrase-based SMT systems resemble a reverse parsing mechanism in the sense that they find the most probable combination of target-language phrases for translating a specific source-language sentence. More information in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_machine_translation).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.
I am a beginner of nlp and MT. I have an idea to use the translator in a mobile environment. So I thought was rule based method is much light weight than SMT. Can you please suggest any parsing mechanism or some thing that I can code to generate sentences. Currently I am trying prolog for this. Still no good clues.

Comment: Any parser will again require the use of a statistical model to select the most probable grammatical derivation, so I'm not sure how much light-weight could be such an idea. First of all, are there any parsers available for your source language? Are you planning to develop your own parser? This could be a project in its own right.